# How to apply css style only for specific Vue component and its child?

Tags: vue.js, scope, styles, components

my `Vue` project use **Vue.Router**.

i want to apply css style for **child components** from parent.
but, i defined css style in parent, it is not applied in **child components**.
and my stylesheet use same class or id selector.

like blow:

list-one.css

```
.foo bar {
    width: 120px;
}
```

not-related-for-list-one.css

```
.foo bar {
    width: 200px;
}
```

two example css file use seperate different Vue components(`ListOne.vue`, `NotForListOne.vue`)

in parent(Vue components, `ListOne.vue`), i define css style several ways, like below:

1. `<style src="my/css/file/path/list-one.css" scope>`
2. `<script>import "my/css/file/path/list-one.css"</script>`
3. `<style scope>my css style here</style>`

> '1' is applied only **parent component**(`ListOne.vue`).
>
> '2' is applied global(`list-one.css` and `not-related-for-list-
>   one.css` both applied `ListOne.vue`) because `NotForListOne.vue` has 
>   `<script>import "my/css/file/path/not-related-for-list-one.css"</script>`.
>
> '3' is same '1'.

ListOne.vue

```
<child-one></child-one>
<child-two></child-two>
<and-other-childs></and-other-childs>
```

list-one.css

```
/* it for ListOne.vue only */
.foo bar {
    width: 120px;
}


/* it for chile-one only */
.foo1 bar {
    display: none;
}

/* it for chile-two only */
.foo2 bar {
    color: red;
}

.
.
.
```

I think most better ways is this:

ListOne.vue

```
....

<style>
.foo bar {
    width: 120px;
}
</style>
```

ChildOne.vue

```
<style>
.foo1 bar {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

ChildTwo.vue

```
<style>
.foo2 bar {
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

but css file is so big, it is so hard to split css for its Vue components.

how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<style scope>my css style here</style>`

try to remove the `scope` from `style` tag.

Comment: kindly confirm if this works for you, so others may know if this is helpful :)